# Blocked outbound ports workaround - W10 Enterprise x64

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

I have 2 machines (W7 Pro x64) in my home network. They are configured to allow RDP connections. However I configured 2 custom ports because I wanted to be able to connect to them at the same time.

(The setup uses no-ip hostnames combined with the dynamic DNS tool to make them accesible.)

At my work outbound ports are blocked. So the 2 custom ports selected are not accesible for outbound traffic. (Common ports like 22, 80, 443, ...) Are allowed.

Question: Is there a way to configure the outbound traffic (work network) to use an open port to connect to my home network using the custom ports I have set.

For example: outbound over port 443 => inbound over 3360 (custom port for RDP connection on my home machines)

Kind regards.

(First time on the forum. If I missed any rules regarding posting. Please be so kind as to instruct me where to post my question. :) )

Comment: The easy solution is changing my inbound/listening ports of the workstations I want to access, yes. But I want to know if there is a workaround for the 'blocked outbound ports'?

Comment: I checked commonly used ports by using portquiz.net. This returned that 'outbound' connections are allowed over certain ports. 

Since I am an employee at a big company I do not have access to the configuration of the firewall regarding outbound ports. Hence my question if it is possible to route my RDP connection over one of the ports noted as open (443, for example) to my home pc which requires incoming connection be over the custom port (3360, which is marked closed at my company).

Comment: Speak to your Computer administrators.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I apologise for not reading the the 'On-Topic' page first. Thanks for pointing out my question is not in the scope of this website.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward all requests coming in via 443 to another port (and even another host)

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=1.2.3.4 connectport=3360 connectaddress=1.2.3.4
```

`listenaddress` and `listenport` are your incoming ip/port and `connectaddress` and `connectport` the destination to forward to. In your case, you would set the `connectadress` to the same address as `listenadress` because you do not want to forward to another host.

Alternatively, you can maybe also solve this transparently to your windows hosts by configuring your router in a similar way (forwarding incoming WAN (internet) requests to a certain host:port).

Comment: "At my work outbound ports are blocked." If the company has blocked the outbound ports, it is improper to give advice on how to circumvent their policy. Speak to your IT department.

Comment: Well, I am discussing the technical issue here. While your objection is valid, I trust people to use their own judgment with regards to their company policies.